# Changing sub-property of state in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

Updating state in ReactJS is not a big deal. But anyone ever experience updating sub-property of state in ReactJS ?

Like I want to update `third` from `first.second.third`, but when I actually do, It is updating the state, but discarding rest of elements in state.

I'm following same syntax that is available on internet. Attached is my code & output. Am I doing any wrong ? Please let me know as this is the only blockage, in updating the analysis object on change of input fields.

```
testing(a,b){
    console.log(a)
    console.log(b)
  this.state = {...this.state.analysis,
    first: {
      second: {
        [a]: b
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(this.state.first)
```

Link that I'm using is:

> http://react-experiments.herokuapp.com/state-flow

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear regarding what is `third` here, but regarding nested state updates, you usually have to make a deep-copy and then update the values in that copy.

Unfortunately, the code for that is quite verbose, so we use helpers like [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) to make it easier. Check out the readme of that link, it also has examples on how to do deep copy without using that library.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the state variable, make it as new variable and modify the state value inside

and then set the new variable to state

```
this.state = {
    fields: {
      second: {
        third: "test"
      }
    }
}

yourFunc() {
  const fields = this.state.fields;
  fields.second.third = "test2";
  this.setState({
    fields: fields
  })
}

render() {
  console.log("this.state.fields = ", this.state.fields);
}
```